# javascript newline character in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to print out some dynamic text to my div called sqlOutput.  I want it to be formatted with newline characters.  I've tried (obviously `<br>` and `/\r\n`). But it didn't work.

How can I have a well formatted text using Angular?

```
$scope.buildScripts = function () {
    var mainTable = "DROP TABLE [dbo].[" + $scope.tableName + "] <br>"
        + "GO <br>"
        + "SET ANSI_NULLS ON <br>"
        + "GO <br>"
        + "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON <br>"
        + "GO <br>"
        + "SET ANSI_PADDING ON <br>"
        + "GO <br>"
        + "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + $scope.tableName + "](";

    $scope.sqlOutput = mainTable;
}
```

Comment: [It might help by using a `<pre>` tag](https://jsfiddle.net/qx7uqf5p/) since newlines are preserved. There is no reason to use `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working example : http://plnkr.co/edit/WgLHP7DzeP9iH9YzNTqY?p=preview

If you want to display in the view some html code from a variable you have to create a filter. this filter will authorise interpreted html code. by default this feature is disabled to prevent security issues.
(more reading [her](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/unsafe) and [her](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) )

1) create a filter  :

```
// Declare the main module
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

angular.module('myApp').filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
   return function (val) {
      if( (typeof val == 'string' || val instanceof String) ) {
         return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
      }
   };
});


myApp.controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope',  function($scope) {
    $scope.tableName = "userXXX" ;
    $scope.buildScripts = function () {
        var mainTable = "DROP TABLE [dbo].[" + $scope.tableName + "] <br>"
            + "GO <br>"
            + "SET ANSI_NULLS ON <br>"
            + "GO <br>"
            + "SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON <br>"
            + "GO <br>"
            + "SET ANSI_PADDING ON <br>"
            + "GO <br>"
            + "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[" + $scope.tableName + "](";

        $scope.sqlOutput = mainTable;
    } 
    $scope.buildScripts();
}]);
```

2) use the filter in the view :

```
<span ng-bind-html="sqlOutput  | unsafe "></span>
```

Comment: That worked great!  Can you explain to me as someone new to Angular why I needed to do all this?